# Solve Wave Equation Initial-Boundary-Value-Problem

Tags: boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

I am trying to solve the following problem and this is my working so far.  I'm struggling to get to the general solution for $X(x)$ as I'm not sure of the $\lambda$ value.  Please could someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Comment: $C\neq 0$ or $X=0$ for all x, so that means that $\sqrt{\lambda} = n\pi$

Answer (score 1):

For non-positive values of $\lambda$ there is no solution. Using the hint of Paul, to obtain:

$$X(x) = C \cos (n\pi x)$$

For $$T(t)= Ae^{-4\lambda t}$$

Now combining....

$$u(x,t)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \cos (n \pi x) e^{ (-4n^2\pi^2 t)}$$

Comment: Am I right to look at $u(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n cos(n \pi x) = cos^2(\pi x)$ as the next step from here? Thanks.

Comment: To my opinion correct.